# Remove package and installed dependencies with apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management

So I install a package

`apt-get install mypackage`

apt-get installs the package with dependencies, and reports that 10 megabytes were installed on my disk.

But I change my mind, so I go

`apt-get remove mypackage`

And apt-get announces that 166 kilobytes will be freed.

I don't want to litter my disk with leftovers, so I try

`apt-get autoremove mypackage`

Now apt-get wants to remove 166 megabytes from my disk.

How do I, you know, undo the last install operation, or just uninstall a single package and **all** its dependencies?

Alternatively, is there another package management tool that I could use (even on different distro), which would roughly treat install operations as atomic operations which can be done and undone?

Comment: `yum` has `history undo`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Thank you. I also discovered that `dnf` also has the ability to autoremove a specific package. I am considering switching to Fedora (I'm on Debian), but I'll try to get `yum` working on Debian first.

Comment: `dnf` is just a successor of `yum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way:

I found that the most reliable way to "undo" an install operation is to look at the apt log and uninstall all packages which were installed by this operation.

Therefore I created a [solution to my problem](https://github.com/rolfen/apt-history). It helps with parsing the apt log and reverting operations.

This is how I would use it:

List latest `apt` operations:

```
apt-history 
96 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
97 apt-get install adb
98 apt-get dist-upgrade
99 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
100 apt-get install qemu-system
```

Display details about all packages which were installed by operation #100 (the last one)

```
sudo apt-history 100 Install
seabios:amd64 (1.10.2-1, automatic), ipxe-qemu:amd64 (1.0.0+git-20161027.b991c67-1, automatic), qemu-system-mips:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3, automatic), openbios-sparc:amd64 (1.1.git20161120-2, automatic), qemu-system-misc:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3, automatic), qemu-system-ppc:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3, automatic), libvdeplug2:amd64 (2.3.2+r586-2.1, automatic), qemu-system-x86:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3, automatic), openhackware:amd64 (0.4.1+git-20140423.c559da7c-4, automatic), libspice-server1:amd64 (0.12.8-2.1+deb9u1, automatic), libxenstore3.0:amd64 (4.8.3+xsa262+shim4.10.0+comet3-1+deb9u6, automatic), qemu-utils:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3, automatic), qemu-efi:amd64 (0~20161202.7bbe0b3e-1, automatic), qemu-system-sparc:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3, automatic), libxen-4.8:amd64 (4.8.3+xsa262+shim4.10.0+comet3-1+deb9u6, automatic), libfdt1:amd64 (1.4.2-1, automatic), qemu-slof:amd64 (20161019+dfsg-1, automatic), qemu-system-arm:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3, automatic), qemu-system-common:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3, automatic), openbios-ppc:amd64 (1.1.git20161120-2, automatic), qemu-system:amd64 (1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u3)
```

Uninstall these packages and their configuration.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `apt-history 100 Install --as-apt-arguments`
```

Warning: to be safe, only do this for the last install command and roll back one command at a time.

Answer (score 7):

APT doesn’t manage package changes as transactions, so there’s no built-in operation to undo a package installation (or any other package manipulation). However, it does log all the operations it performs, grouped by end-user request: if you look in `/var/log/apt/history.log`, you’ll find the `mypackage` installation, along with a list of all the other packages which were installed automatically alongside it. You can use this to undo the installation manually.

You could also use `aptitude` instead, for your general package management: it effectively `autoremove`s by default. This won’t help you right now though since it will want to remove the same 166MiB of packages as `apt autoremove`.

As pointed out by [Weijun Zhou](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/259023/weijun-zhou), `yum` and `dnf` do manage package changes as units which can be undone (in some circumstances). `dnf history` will list the transactions stored in the history, and `dnf history rollback` or `dnf history undo` can be used to roll the history back or undo a specific transaction (if possible). I’m not sure `yum` or `dnf` can be used properly instead of APT on Debian-based systems; you might need to switch to Fedora, RHEL or CentOS if you want to use those tools for all your package management.

Comment: Thank you. I think that apt should have the ability to "autoremove" a specific package. In this particular case, it would have the same effect, and would also be an acceptable solution.
Indeed `yum` and `dnf` deal with RPM packages. Debian is packaged in 'deb' packages. Trying to replace APT with `yum` or `dnf` on a Debian system seems impractical.

Comment: A package-specific `autoremove` couldn’t always be relied upon to undo a package installation, because the package installation might have pulled in a package which is of interest to some other installed package. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264935/86440) for an example where this wouldn’t work.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. However I'm sure it's possible, with edge cases, of course. What I'm seeing is apt-get installing suggested and recommended package, then not removing them, which is default behavior. I want to modify this behavior (in the uninstall stage) but only for a specific package.

Comment: I understand what you’re after, I’m just saying it can’t be done currently. If `apt-get remove --autoremove mypackage` only removed autoremovable packages which were in `mypackage`’s dependency tree, it would give the results you’re after (or close enough), but it currently doesn’t do that. There *is* one way of getting what you’re after currently, but it relies on a process change rather than a tool change: never leave autoremovable packages lying around — either always remove them, or mark them as manually installed if you want to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Stephen's answer I used

```
UNINSTALL_THIS=cockpit
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -Po "Install: \K.*$UNINSTALL_THIS.*" | sed -E 's/:[^\)]*\),*//g'
```

to print a copy-pastable list of the packages to remove for `cockpit` to use `sudo apt remove <paste>`

For explanation of the grep command see: [What does grep -Po '...\K...' do? How else can that effect be achieved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524643/what-does-grep-po-k-do-how-else-can-that-effect-be-achieved)