# How to prevent APT from keeping packages I didn't install?

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, aptitude

When I install packages via `apt-get install <package>` or `aptitude install <package>` and remove them afterwards with `apt-get purge <package>; apt-get autoremove --purge`, my system is not in the same state as before. It still has additional packages installed.

The additional packages are marked as automatically installed, as indicated by `apt-mark showauto`.

Namely this happens under Ubuntu 18.04 with `g++-8`, leaving `cpp-8 gcc-8 libasan5:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 libgcc-8-dev:amd64 libisl19:amd64 libmpc3:amd64 libmpfr6:amd64 libstdc++-8-dev:amd64 libubsan1:amd64`.
Is there a clean way to prevent this, in the sense of not having to parse APTs output?

Comment: What does `aptitude why gcc-8` say? (I’m not trying to solve this particular instance, but I have a theory which I’d like to check before writing an answer.)

Comment: The output is `i   g++-8 Depends gcc-8 (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1)`.

Comment: After removal it's ```i   libxml2-dev      Depends    libicu-dev
    i A libicu-dev       Depends    libicu-le-hb-dev
    i A libicu-le-hb-dev Depends    libharfbuzz-dev
    i A libharfbuzz-dev  Depends    libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.19.1)
    i A libglib2.0-dev   Depends    pkg-config
    i A pkg-config       Depends    dpkg-dev
    i A dpkg-dev         Recommends gcc | c-compiler
    i A gcc-8            Provides   c-compiler```

Comment: If I use `aptitude remove/purge` it works for `g++-8`, but the problem still occurs for `g++`. The output is the same as above, except with `7` instead of `8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `autoremove` isn’t removing as much as you expect is that the packages which were installed automatically satisfy weak dependencies of other packages you already had installed. In your case, `dpkg-dev` is already installed, itself as an automatic dependency; because it recommends the virtual `c-compiler` package, any package providing `c-compiler` will be kept after it’s installed.

Put another way, you have package A already installed with a weak dependency on package B, and package B isn’t installed. If you later install package C, with a dependency (strong or weak, but taken into account by `apt`’s configuration) on package B, package B will also be installed, and marked as automatically installed. Removing package C however won’t cause package B to be considered for auto-removal, because package A keeps it “interesting” as far as `apt` is concerned.

You *could* ask `autoremove` to ignore weak dependencies (recommendations, by default), but that would probably cause a lot more packages to become removable than you’d expect or want.

I’m not aware of any good solution for this. `aptitude` is somewhat more agressive in its automatic removals, but it doesn’t handle all situations either.

See [How do recommends and suggests interact with apt-get dist-upgrade and apt-get autoremove?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447952/86440) and [Why did 'apt-get autoremove' not work properly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264935/86440) for more on this.